# Search Icon in string in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, icons, uisearchbar

I am making contact list kind view in my application. As contact application there is search icon on the top of the alphabet list as shown in image . I want to do this same but we can not add the image in the array for sectionIndexTitlesForTableView in this method

So meas I need that character of that image.

Do any one know how to make that character in array....[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235120/whats-the-uitableview-index-magnifying-glass-character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `@"{search}"` at the beginning of your array, or simply the constant `UITableViewIndexSearch` (best).

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is **UITableViewIndexSearch**, sample code from my app available in App Store:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
NSMutableArray *titles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.myList count]+1];
[titles addObject:UITableViewIndexSearch];

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{
    for (NSString *item in self.filteredList)
        [titles addObject:[item substringToIndex:1]];
}
else
{
    for (NSString *item in self.myList)
        [titles addObject:[item substringToIndex:1]];
}
return titles;
}
```

Few additional comments in my blog article "[How to Get Magnifying Glass into UITableView Index](http://jomnius.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-get-magnifying-glass-into.html)" (sorry about the link, didn't want to copy & paste all the stuff).