# How to implement a magnifying glass in the index list of an UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to implement a magnifying glass in the index list of an UITableView in Swift.
Here is how it should look like:

[image]
Is there a simple way to achieve it? The magnifying glass should be a button. By pressing this button something like

```swift
tableView.scroll(to: .top, animated: true)
```

should be executed...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235120/whats-the-uitableview-index-magnifying-glass-character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the icon easily enough:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614959-indexsearch

But what it does is not up to you. You really don't need a button to scroll to top anyway; it's built in (the user just taps on the status bar).

Comment: Thanks! But when I add countrySection.insert(UITableView.indexSearch, at: 0), then it doesn't work in the right way, because the first section has then a title of {search}.

Comment: You have to implement https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614933-tableview to configure the correspondence between index and sections.

Comment: Ok, could you please post what exactly I have to configure in the named method. I have never worked with this one so far...

Comment: You've been given lots of links.